# Programming a Counter for a Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, counter

My goal is to programm an Counter-Application. There is a picture in the middle of the smartphone and under the picture is a countdown starting at 100.

Every time you click on the picture the picture should flash and the counter should decrease till you have clicked 100 times and reached 0.

I have a little bit of code, but every time I run the project on my VM the application crashes.

```
package com.syntaix.appleclicker;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.appel);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter--;
                text.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the LogCat Screenshot:
[LogCat](http://s1.directupload.net/images/140324/o9bq5igo.jpg)

Comment: Please post the logcat output that is written during the crash. There should be an exception somewhere.

Comment: I edited at the end of my description

Comment: You have a NullPointerException somewhere in your onCreate(). I would recommend setting a breakpoint at the line `image.setOnClickListener()` and making sure that both `text` and `image` are not null. In fact, I am most certain that `image` is null. Are you sure that the id of the image view is `R.id.appel` in your xml layout?

Comment: Issue should be in your layout

Comment: What is the purpose of the `PlaceholderFragment` and where do you have  your `TextView` and `ImageView` defined, in `R.layout. activity_main` or `R.layout.fragment_main`?

Comment: Ehm the PlaceholderFragment was created when I have created the whole project :D

In my R.layout.fragment_main

Comment: You can find the textview only after the fragment is attached. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the views in fragment when its created . But your are trying to get the views before attaching the fragment to the activity. You need to move some code to fragment as below...

MainActivity.java

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
  }
```

PlaceholderFragment.java

```
  public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    int counter = 100;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        final TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        final ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.appel);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter--;
                text.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```